# How can I execute task in specific role from playbook

Tags: ansible, prometheus

I have monitoring playbook with few roles include prometheus. And today I need to update prometheus targets without executing all role for him.
I have tags for role in playbook and tags for tasks in role.
This command execute all tasks include reloading etc., but I need to execute only one task "push-targets.yml"
`ansible-playbook -vv -k /monioring-book.yml --limit "prom-node01"  --tags "prometheus_deploy"`
It seems like
`ansible-playbook -vv -k /monioring-book.yml --limit "prom-node01"  --tags "prometheus_deploy" --tags-in-role "push-targets"`
Is it possible?

I tried to
`ansible-playbook -vv -k /push-targets.yml --limit "prom-node01"`
But its getting down with expecting error like "'import_tasks' is not valid attribute for a Play" because push-targets.yml is not a playbook

Example:

monitoring-book.yml (Playbook with few roles)

```
- name: Install and configure prometheus
  hosts: prom-node01
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  roles:
    - role: roles/applications/prometheus
  tags:
    - prometheus_deploy
```

Prometheus role tree

```
prometheus
│
└───defaults
└───handlers  
└───tasks
│   │   prepare.yml
│   │   install.yml
│   │   config.yml
│   │   targets.yml
│   │   main.yml
└───templates
└───vars
        main_targets.yml
        sec_targets.yml
```

I need to execute task targets.yml which:

```
- include_vars: sec_targets.yml  
  
- name: push prometheus target files
  template:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /etc/prometheus
  with_items: 
    - 1st_lits.json
    - 2nd_list.json
```

Its untagged, but main.yml have tagged task:

```
# tasks file for prometheus
- name: Preparing for Prometheus deployment
  import_tasks: prepare.yml
  tags:
    - prometheus-prepare

- name: Installing Prometheus on host
  import_tasks: install.yml
  tags:
    - prometheus-install

- name: Push main config file and alertrules to host
  import_tasks: config.yml
  tags:
    - prometheus-config-node
    
- name: Push target configs
  import_tasks: targets.yml
  tags:
    - push-targets
```

So, executing my ansible command looks like:

```
ansible-playbook -vv -u user -K /monitoring-book.yml --limit "prom-node01" --tags "prometheus_deploy,push-targets"
```

caused the "push-targets" tag to be ignored and all tasks from the role to run

Comment: Have you tried `--tags "prometheus_deploy,push-targets"`? The fact that a tag is in a role or not should not influence anything, I believe.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Are you saying that the 'prometheus-deploy' tag is applied to the playbook first, and the 'push-targets' tag is applied to the role?

Comment: No, both are applied on all tasks If your tags are at the tag level (which I am assuming, but since you don't have an [mre], that could be a bad assumption indeed).

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I've edited the question, hopefully to the bare minimum required

Comment: So, yes, at a first glance what I stated seems like it would do, as adding a tag on a role is merely doing: [_Add the same tag or tags to all tasks in the role by setting tags under `roles`. See examples in this section._](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tags.html#adding-tags-to-roles)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I've tried your suggestion on test instance, and its seem like "push-targets" tag was ignored and all tasks, including preparing, installing and config was executed

Comment: Oh, my bad, this is because you actually put your tag at **the play level** so, all your tasks are tagged prometheus_deploy.

Comment: `--tags "push-targets"`, then.